# For $u:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, if $u \in W^{n,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, then what is the regularity of $\nabla \cdot u$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, matrix-norms, divergence-operator

For $u:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, if $u \in W^{n,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, then what is the regularity of $\nabla \cdot u$?

From the definition of a Sobolev space I think it follows immediately that
$$
u \in W^{n,p}(\mathbb{R}^3) \implies
\nabla ^k u \in W^{n-k,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)
$$
assuming $n>k$.

The question is whether
$$
u \in W^{n,p}(\mathbb{R}^3) \implies
\nabla \cdot u \in W^{n,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)
$$

In this case $u$ is a vector function and therefore $\nabla u$ is the Jacobian. Therefore we know that given that $u$ is in some Sobolev space, the Jacobian is also bounded with respect to the same norm.

In the case of $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ the operator/matrix norm reduces to a simple sum of the absolute value of the elements, e.g. for $p=1$
$$
\|\nabla u \| = \max_j \sum_i \left|\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\right| 
$$
from which one can see that the divergence is then also bounded. Similarly for $p=\infty$.

In case $p=2$ the p-norm is bounded by the Frobenius norm which results in the same answer.

What about the general case?

Comment: $\operatorname{div} u$ is a sum of components (the trace) of $\nabla u$ so of course.

Comment: (I assume you meant to write $W^{n-1,p}$ in the question.)